# Desactivar un elemento de Bootstap desde un If

Tags: javascript, html, c#, html5, bootstrap

Migre de una tabla a un Navbar de Bootstrap
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 pero necesito desactivar ciertos elementos de esta cuando se cumpla un IF en el .cs asi lo hacia en la tabla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Obviamente se que no funcionaria igual pero es solo ilustrativo el problema es que no puedo encontrar la forma de como desactivar los elementos de NavBar cuando se cumpla el if como lo hacia en la tabla, les dejo mi codigo html a ver si me pueden ayudar

>

```html
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bienvenido <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Login.aspx">Inicio</a>
      </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Usuario</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="nuevoUsuario.aspx">Nuevo</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="modDelUsuario.aspx">Modificar o Eliminar</a>
              </div>
      </li>
             </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPuesto" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Puesto</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPuesto">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="nuevoPuesto.aspx">Nuevo</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="modDelPuesto.aspx">Modificar o Eliminar</a>
              </div>
      </li>
           <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownHospital" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Hospital</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownHospital">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="nuevoHospital.aspx">Nuevo</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="modDelHospital.aspx">Modificar o Eliminar</a>
              </div>
      </li>

           <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownSala" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Sala</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownSala">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="nuevoSala.aspx">Nuevo</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="modDelSala.aspx">Modificar o Eliminar</a>
              </div>
      </li>
           <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPersonal" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Personal</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPersonal">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="nuevoPersonal.aspx">Nuevo</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="modDelPersonal.aspx">Modificar o Eliminar</a>
              </div>
      </li>
           <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPaciente" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Paciente</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPaciente">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="nuevoPaciente.aspx">Nuevo</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="modDelPaciente.aspx">Modificar o Eliminar</a>
              </div>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el condicionador `if` en el contexto html utilizando tu `tipoUsuario`:

```
    ...
    <%if (tipoUsuario=="Operador") {%>
    <div>
        ... Menu completo del operador
    </div>
    <%}%>
    <%else if (tipoUsuario=="Consultor") {%>
    <div>
        ... Menu completo del consultor
    </div>
    <%}%>
```

Sin embargo, estarás duplicando contenido `HTML`.

Otra solución es crear un bloque javascript y crear una variable que reciba el rol, luego en una funcion `document.ready`(suponiendo que utilizas jQuery) agregar o quitar los menús de cada perfil:

```
    ...
    <script>
        var rol = '<%=tipoUsuario%>'
        $(function() {
            if(rol==='Operador'){
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
        })
    </script>
```